# What is the workflow for adding customized Drupal files on OpenShift?

Tags: git, drupal, ssh, openshift

I just created a Drupal instance on OpenShift. I've cloned the repo to my local machine, and I understand the actual Drupal core files are not part of this repo. How exactly can I get a custom theme onto the site?

Should I save a snapshot of my app, develop locally then restore the snapshot with my local changes?

I just want to be able to upload customized theme code, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might move this comment to be an answer and then mark it as correct, then you can get more uproots on it also.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I overlooked this, but there is a Drupal quick installation repo you can find here github.com/openshift-quickstart/… . Basically, instead of using the "Drupal" quick install on OpenShift, just create a new OpenShift app manually that utilizes PHP and MySQL, and just manually create the Drupal site. This will give you full git access to the repo just like a regular github account would.